# "I don't think you should drive until you've had your brakes fixed" I don't understand this sentence

Tags: tense

> I don't think you should drive until you've had your brakes fixed

Why do we use here "until you have had your brakes fixed" not "until you have your brakes fixed"? ...

Answer (score 3):

the "have had" construction makes it clear that the driving should happen only **after** the break repair.  That said, the form "until you have your brakes fixed" is also used, and is perfectly acceptable. The meaning is unchanged.